# What is the difference between ((+) 4) and \x -> (+) 4 x?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand CAF from the page https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form and confuse about the difference between `((+) 4)` and `\x -> (+) 4 x`?

Why is the first a CAF and the later not? As a beginner, I can not see the difference.

Comment: Why does it matter?  99.9% of the time, it's an implementation detail.  0.1% of the time, it's a minor detail in optimization.

Comment: The distinction only matters to compiler writers, not to language users.

Comment: Without certain optimizations, `\x -> (+) (fib 23)` will recompute `fib 23` every application because it's under a lambda, whereas `(+ fib 23)` won't. But with "full laziness" (which I think is on by default with -O) they become equivalent.  You can test this difference in ghci though.

Answer (score 3):

One way to read this is that:

- `((+) 4)` is an expression that produces the function: `\x -> (+) 4 x`
- `\x -> (+) 4 x` is that function already.

And functions are not CAFs (we don't apply anything there).